# What is the equivalent of "Alt-Insert" in IntelliJ for Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, intellij-idea

What is the equivalent of "Alt-Insert" in IntelliJ for Mac OS X?

Many Mac keyboards does not have insert keys, and even when connecting a PC keyboard, the `insert` key is not functioning.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

The equivalent shortcut on macOS is <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>

See the official IntelliJ IDEA documentation: [Generate code](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/generating-code.html).

Comment: `ctrl+n` for me, depends on your keymap

Answer (score 29):

Funnily enough, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> also works for me.

Answer (score 13):

you can also use "ctrl + enter"

Comment: This should be the accepted one as it's redirecting to default behavior. We can always override them as specified here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/41921106/4209887 .

Answer (score 9):

It may depend on your keymap. I recommend using the *10.5+* keymap wich is optimized for Mac OS (ie cmd-w is *close tab* and not *incremental select*). In that case *code generate*, which you are referring to, is cmd-n.

Answer (score 6):

"option + return"

is what worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

It is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>.
This worked for me

Answer (score 2):

In both IntelliJ or Android Studio you can set it to whatever you want. I use an Apple keyboard and a KVM to switch between my Mac and PC. The keyboard doesn't have an insert key so I had to change it to simply the 'Back Quote' which is just below the esc key on my Apple keyboard. From the Main menu go..

File > Settings

then

Keymap > Main menu > Code > Generate..

to edit, right click (or use the green pencil) and select 'Remove existing shortcut' or 'Add another one'. The IDE will warn you if the key or combination of keys are already used.

Comment: I changed keymap to Windows shortcut. However, I don't have `insert` key on the keyboard -> created a shortcut for it `Command` + `n`. And it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I have Mac and **`option+return`** work for me for **`android studio 4`**

Answer (score -2):

In case of usage NetBeans for calling constructor, use Ctrl+i